# How to securely pass values from SuiteScript suitelet to an HTML page?

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am attempting to pass values from a Suitelet to an HTML page that is being inserted into an INLINEHTML field in the Suitelet form. However, I am unsure of the best way to accomplish this. I am currently doing it in this manner, but I want to ensure that I am using a somewhat secure method ideally, as opposed to allowing for XSS vulnerabilities.

Suitelet INLINEHTML field:

```
var htmlForm = form.addField({
    id: 'custpage_htmlform',
    type: ui.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
    label: 'HTMLFORM'
});

var fileObj = file.load({
    id: 123
});

var htmlContent = fileObj.getContents();
htmlContent = htmlContent.replace("['REPLACETHIS']","['<input type=\"radio\" name=\"selectRow\" />','EXAMPLE','1234','1245','01/2021','<img src=\"https://imageurl.example" />'];");
htmlForm.defaultValue = htmlContent;
```

HTML example:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
</table>
<br />

<script>
    //Main Data Table    
    var exampleValues = new Array();

    var exampleDetailArr = ['REPLACETHIS'];
    exampleValues.push(exampleDetailArr);

    window.$vars = {
        exampleValues: exampleValues
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: exampleValues,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        columns: [
            { title: "Select" },
            { title: "Type" },
            { title: "Internal ID" },
            { title: "External ID "},
            { title: "Date" },
            { title: "Memo" },
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 3 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }
    ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```